# CNFT metadata structure

Tags: plutus, nft, metadata, metadata.json

So I am working on a NFT minting and I checked the CIP-25 for metadata descriptions and I am confused regarding the naming of the NFT.

What is really the name of the NFT? (as in recognized by JPG.store) Is it the TokenName that is recognized by smart contracts or is it the name specified in the metadata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For display purpose, people generally use the "name" attribute from the CIP-25 metadata, not the <asset_name>.

https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip25/:

```
{
  "721": {
    "<policy_id>": {
      "<asset_name>": {
        "name": <string>,
        "image": <uri | array>
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the asset name attached to the TokenName variable used in smart contracts